# $('#formId').submit() is not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to `upload` a form using `JQuery` but `$('#formId').submit()` is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload Pricing</title>
        <META CHARSET="UTF-8">
        <META lang="en">
        <META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <style>
            .uploadWrapper{
                width: 100%;
                max-width: 400px;
                margin: 30px auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="uploadWrapper">
                        <h3>Upload Document for Pricing</h3>
                        <form id="docForm" method="post" action="<?PHP $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label><em>* </em>User Type:</label>
                                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="userType">
                                    <option value="all">All</option>
                                    <option value="restaurant">Restaurant</option>
                                    <option value="channelPartner">Channel Partner</option>
                                    <option value="agent">Delivery Agent</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label><em>* </em>Select Document (pdf):</label>
                                <input type="file" class="input-sm" id="doc" name="doc">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="submit" class="input-sm" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                                <span class="status"></span>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#submit').click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var doc = $('#doc').val();
                    var extension = doc.substring(doc.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, doc.length);
                    extension = extension.toLowerCase();
                    if ( doc == '' ) {
                        $('.status').html('Please select pricing document');
                    }
                    else if( extension != 'pdf' ){
                        $('.status').html('Document must be a pdf');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#docForm').submit();
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the last else part why not `$('#submit').submit()`?

Comment: can be action problem. add echo before $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

Comment: @caramba Tried your idea. Still not working. After clicking submit button doesn't happen anything

Comment: @AshishPatel not working yet. Doesn't happen anything

Comment: open up console. and tell us the error.

Comment: Does the submit work without the jQuery/javascript code? It should work without it!

Comment: @SantanuBiswas did you check that all your conditions are fine & the execution controller is coming to the `else` part. ?

Comment: No error message in console. Yes the form works without JQery/Javascript

Comment: @RohitBatra Yes I have checked that. The else part is executing but the form is not get submitting

Comment: @SantanuBiswas on a different note:  replace this `<select class="form-control input-sm" id="userType">` with `<select class="form-control input-sm" id="userType" name="userType" >`

Comment: @RohitBatra still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem comes from `e.preventDefault();` in your click handle you already told that you want to prevent submit from happening. If you move that line accordingly to if statement

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function(e) {
      var doc = $('#doc').val();
      var extension = doc.substring(doc.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, doc.length);
      extension = extension.toLowerCase();
      if (doc == '') {
        $('.status').html('Please select pricing document');
        e.preventDefault();
      } else if (extension != 'pdf') {
        $('.status').html('Document must be a pdf');
        e.preventDefault();
      } else {
        $('#docForm').submit();
      }
    });
  });
```

Your `$('#docForm').submit()` will be executed. But since this is already a submit handle last `else` as well as `$('#docForm').submit();` can be omitted as it does not really matter.